# How to resolve exception with Selenium & ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running ChromeDriver (v89) & Selenium 4.1 on MacOS and am getting an exception when instantiating ChromeDriver by passing an instance of `ChromeDriverService` and these options:

```
{
   "browserName": "chrome",
   "goog:chromeOptions": {
      "args": [
         "no-sandbox"
      ],
      "debuggerAddress": "127.0.0.1:8080"
   }
}
```

Details of the exception:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:49385/session timed out after 60 seconds.
---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation canceled.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (89): Operation canceled
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)    at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options)
```

The same code worked fine on Windows, so I dare to say that it's been tested.

Libraries I'm using:

```
OpenQA,/Users/mbaas/.nuget/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/4.1.0/lib/netstandard2.1/WebDriver.dll
OpenQA.Selenium,/Users/mbaas/.nuget/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/4.1.0/lib/netstandard2.1/WebDriver.dll
OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome,/Users/mbaas/.nuget/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/4.1.0/lib/netstandard2.1/WebDriver.dll
Newtonsoft.Json,/Users/mbaas/.nuget/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/12.0.3/lib/netstandard2.0/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
OpenQA.Selenium.Support,/Users/mbaas/.nuget/packages/Selenium.Support/4.1.0/lib/netstandard2.1/WebDriver.Support.dll
OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI,/Users/mbaas/.nuget/packages/Selenium.Support/4.1.0/lib/netstandard2.1/WebDriver.Support.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer: the plan was to launch a separate process beforehand that runs CEF and the site - but that step failed, so there is no browser it could talk to.
My bad - I should have checked that before posting here.